# Failed to call postgress function with spring SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I had a problem with calling postgress function from spring-jdbc SimpleJdbcCall class, so I simplified an issue.
I have postgress 13.3, and a simple function on empty test database:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_test()
RETURNS table (field1 int, field2 varchar)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
    return query
    select
        1 as field1,
        cast('f-1' as varchar) as field2
    union all
    select
        2 as field1,
        cast('f-2' as varchar) as field2
    ;
END;
$$
;
```

So, I am using packages spring-jdbc 5.3.8 postgresql 42.2.20 and when I try to run the code below - **case #2** workes fine, but **case #1** (when uncommented) - fails with exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement function was executed and the out parameter 1 was of type java.sql.Types=4 however type java.sql.Types=1111 was registered.
```

**Case code:**

```java
public class AppTest {

    private static final String LIST_RESULT_NAME = "list";

    static class Dto {

        private String field1;

        private String field2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerNames(new String[]{"localhost"});
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("test");
        dataSource.setUser("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("pA**w0rd");
        dataSource.setPortNumbers(new int[]{5432});

        // case #1 fails
        // testCaseOne(dataSource);
        
        // case #2 works fine
        testCaseTwo(dataSource);
    }

    private static void testCaseOne(PGSimpleDataSource dataSource) {
        final SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withSchemaName("public")
            .withFunctionName("fn_test")
            .returningResultSet("list", AppTest::map) // NOT WORKING, SEEMS USELESS
            ;

        final Map<String, Object> result = jdbcCall.execute(Collections.emptyMap());
        final Object list = result.get(LIST_RESULT_NAME);
        Assert.isInstanceOf(List.class, list);
    }

    private static void testCaseTwo(PGSimpleDataSource dataSource) {
        final SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withSchemaName("public")
            .withProcedureName("fn_test")
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess() // WITHOUT IT FAILS TO CONVERT ResultSet TO List
            ;

        // MANUALLY ADDING SqlReturnResultSet
        jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet(LIST_RESULT_NAME, AppTest::map));

        final Map<String, Object> result = jdbcCall.execute(Collections.emptyMap());
        final Object list = result.get(LIST_RESULT_NAME);
        Assert.isInstanceOf(List.class, list);
    }

    private static Dto map(ResultSet resultSet, int rowId) throws SQLException {
        final Dto dto = new Dto();
        dto.field1 = resultSet.getString("field1");
        dto.field2 = resultSet.getString("field2");
        return dto;
    }
}
```

After some code digging I found spring class [PostgresCallMetaDataProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.8/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/metadata/PostgresCallMetaDataProvider.java#L45), which has method:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean isReturnResultSetSupported() {
        return false;
    }
```

This method is called from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.8/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/metadata/CallMetaDataContext.java#L269),  and it`s result (false) affects on ResultSet mappers.

**So, my question: is there an error in method PostgresCallMetaDataProvider#isReturnResultSetSupported() or am I using SimpleJdbcCall improperly.**

Comment: Found related [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21250) at spring github.com

Comment: Why so complicated? You can simply run a `select * from fn_test()`. Calling a set-returning function is no different than running a "normal" SELECT statement